# How do I use a custom class based validator for multiple fields in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I need to validate a field depending on another field with multiple validators like so:

```py
logged_in_id = serializers.UUIDField(validators=[Internal() | LoggedIn()])
```

where `Internal` and `LoggedIn` are class based validators:

```
class LoggedIn:
    def __call__(self, value):
        if other_id == value:  # other_id is another field like logged_in_id
            return True
        return False
```

Can I access the `validated_data` of the serializer in a validator class somehow? Or write a validator class not for a specific field, but for the whole serializer, like the `validate` function?

Docs: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linked docs didn't explicitly mention that you can access all fields by declaring the validators in the Meta class of the serializer:

```
class Meta:
   validators = [
            Internal() | LoggedIn()
        ]
```

```
class LoggedIn:
    def __call__(self, attrs):
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The validators field in the serializer field is only for one field, you want something like

```
class PotatoSerializer(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        validators = [
            OneMustBeGreaterThan5Validator(field_1, field_2)
        ]
```

And this could be achieved with a class with `__call__` that has the following definition:

```
def __call__(self, attrs, serializer):
    # logic
```

And for a good example, the `UniqueTogetherValidator` in rest_framework.validators is sufficient, see it [here](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/validators.py#:%7E:text=class-,UniqueTogetherValidator,-%3A)